# Tossing coin until heads

Tags: estimation

We perform independent Bernoulli trials with unknown probability of success P.
We perform them by series, each of 1000 trials, and stop when at least one success happens.
So the number of trials N is a multiple of 1000, and the number of successes K is 1 through 1000.
How can one estimate P?
The maximum likelihood estimator is K/N. Is it good?

Comment: I think your question is phrased in a confusing fashion. You have a "coin" with a certain "bias" P. Your standard mode of operation is to flip the coin until it comes up heads, and count the number of flips required to achieve this. Is this what you consider to be one "trial"? Re the number 1000, does that mean that you stop at 1000 flips if you don't have success, or do you do 1000 successive "trials", each of some unknown (in advance) number of flips (which could exceed 1000)?

Comment: One trial is flipping coin just once; each trial can be either a success (with probability P) or a failure.

Comment: Note that N and K are independent random quantities.

Comment: Sounds to be like typical sequences would be: 0/1000, 0/1000, 0/1000, 1/1000, stop. 0/1000, 1/1000, stop. 1/1000, stop. Is this correct or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: The only a priori assumption is P>0. For P<<0.001, a typical sequence is 0/1000, ..., 0/1000, 1/1000, stop. For P>>0.001, it is typical something like 77/1000, stop. For P~0.001, a typical example is 0/1000, 0/1000, 3/1000, stop.

Comment: It would appear that k and N are not independent. To wit, if N is large then k is likely small; if N is small then k is likely large.

Comment: For every P, the random variables N and K are independent.
Two discrete random variables X and Y are independent
if Prob(X=x,Y=y) can be expressed as f(x)g(y).
In our case, Prob(N=n,K=k) = binom(1000,k) (1-P)^(n-k) P^k = (1-P)^n * binom(1000,k) (P/(1-P))^k.

Comment: If we average the distribution of (N,K) over all P, the resulting distribution will not be a product. Indeed, as you noted, if N is large then k is likely small; if N is small then k is likely large.

Answer (score 2):

Bayesian techniques may help answer this.

Suppose you start with a [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the prior distribution for $P$.  After $1000$ flips and $K$ successes, the posterior distribution will again be a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha + K$ and $\beta +1000-K$.  If $K$ is positive then you can stop there; if it is zero, you can repeat, but using the new parameters for the prior for the next set of $1000$ flips.

Eventually you will stop (with probability $1$), and then the posterior distribution will have parameters $\alpha + K$ and $\beta +N-K$.  This does not just give you a central estimate for $P$ with the expected value being $\dfrac{\alpha + K}{\alpha + \beta + N}$, but also a way of looking at the uncertainty in this estimate of $P$.

Note that if originally you started with the improper parameters $\alpha=\beta=0$ then the central estimate will be $\frac{K}{N}$.  There are also arguments for starting with $\alpha=\beta=\frac{1}{2}$ or $\alpha=\beta=1$, but these differences in initial assumptions usually only affect the final distribution slightly when you have large samples.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p = Pr(\text{sucess})$

Let $N = \text{number of 1000-throw trials}$

Let $k = \text{number of success in the final trial that stops the sequence}$

$L=(1-p)^{1000(N-1)} {1000 \choose{k}} p^{k} (1-p)^{1000-k}$

Maximizing, $\hat{p}={k \over{1000N}}$

As you suggested.

Comment: Based on the set-up, my guess is you are looking for an extraordinarily rare event. Given this assumption, I would not expect a high likelihood of 2+ successes in any of the 1000-trials. 2+ successes are taken into account in the 2nd step here as $\hat{p}'$ is estimated. It would appear the major factor driving your problem is the "do-until" part, which would suggest much more a geometric distribution.

Comment: The question is, can you recommend this estimate?